# ListView Control not installed under Excel-2016

Tags: excel, vba, listview

I'm using Windows 10 and Excel 2016 and I tried to install the Windows Common Controls (SP6) using the file mscomctl.ocx.

I performed the following steps:

1. Copy the mscomctl.ocx file into the folder C:\Windows\SysWow64
2. Register the file with the cmd prompt regsvr32 C:\Windows\SysWow64\mscomctl.ocx
3. Referenced the mscomctl.ocx in VBA which appeard then in the list with a checked box
4. Checked the registry and theres only an entry for Version 2

Step N. 5 would have been adding the control to the Standard controls but None of the common controls does appear in the list.

Does anybody have experienced similary issues?

Comment: Is your Excel 64-bit or 32-bit version? As far as I know there is no 64-bit version of the ListView control.

Comment: my excel-2016 is a 64-bit version

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure you install the 64 bit version of ListView otherwise you will not be able to add it.

Actually the ListView and TreeView are already installed by default (at my Win 10, Excel 2016 x64 1902). So there is no need to install something extra.
Just make sure you are on the latest update and click in VBE menu: `Extras` » `Additional Controls …` where you should find *Microsoft ListView Control, version 6.0*:

[image]

If you don't find it there is probably something wrong with your installed Office, try to update first, if it doesn't help repair/re-install Office.